Any way to replace multiple Replace String commands with a single line?
${rowNum}    Convert To String    ${iRowNum}

${ScheduledJobManager_T1_Col_1_Row_i}    Replace String    ${ScheduledJobManager_T1_JobID}    <rowNum>    ${rowNum}

${ScheduledJobManager_T1_Col_3_Row_i}    Replace String    ${ScheduledJobManager_T1_JobName}    <rowNum>    ${rowNum}

${ScheduledJobManager_T1_Col_5_Row_i}    Replace String    ${ScheduledJobManager_T1_CreatedBy} <rowNum>    ${rowNum}

${ScheduledJobManager_T1_Col_10_Row_i}    Replace String    ${ScheduledJobManager_T1_ViewDetails} <rowNum>    ${rowNum}

Here Replace string is used many times, Is there a way we can write this in a single line?

It would be way easier if you would create a list and place the values of all of your  ScheduledJobManager_T1_Col_index_Row_i values into that list..

This is what I eventually did!

Found a way:
${col_values}    Create List       
        FOR  ${col}  IN  ${ScheduledJobManager_T1_JobID}    ${ScheduledJobManager_T1_JobName}    ${ScheduledJobManager_T1_CreatedBy}    ${ScheduledJobManager_T1_ViewDetails}
            ${col}    Replace String    ${col}    <rowNum>    ${rowNum}
            Append To List    ${col_values}    ${col}
        END

Using ${col_values}[index_value] instead of extra variables created.
Would love to know if there is a better way to do this.
